# SOAP Response converting to CSV

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, csv

```
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns0:DataResponse xmlns:ns0="http://somenamspace/v1.0">
             <ns0:ResponseId>
                <ns0:RequestID>12345</ns0:RequestID>
             </ns0:ResponseId>
             <ns0:Payload>
                <ns1:Product xmlns:ns1="http://anothernamespace/v1.x">
                   <ns1:ProductName>productName</ns1:ProductName>
                   <ns1:ProductIdentifier>12222</ns1:ProductIdentifier>
                   <ns1:ProdInst>
                      <ns1:Type>Conv</ns1:Type>
                      <ns1:Descr>Conventional Loan</ns1:Descr>
                      <ns1:AllowedTypes>
                         <ns1:ScheduleSchedule>true</ns1:ScheduleSchedule>
                      </ns1:AllowedTypes>
                      <ns1:prdExist>false</ns1:prdExist>
                      <ns1:AdditionalAttributes>
                         <ns1:AdditionalAttribute name="gura" value="C"/>
                      </ns1:AdditionalAttributes>
                   </ns1:ProdInst>
                   <ns1:ProductGroups>
                      <ns1:ProductGroupName>1111</ns1:ProductGroupName>
                      <ns1:ProductGroupName>2222</ns1:ProductGroupName>
                   </ns1:ProductGroups>
                </ns1:Product>
                 <ns1:Product>
                   .......
                 </ns1:Product>
             </ns0:Payload>
          </ns0:DataResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
------------------------------------
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace/v1.0"
        xmlns:ns1="http://anothernamespace/v1.x"
        exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" method="text"/>

        <xsl:template match="ns1:Products">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
----------------------------------------------------
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://namespace/v1.x"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="ns1:Product">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:ProductName" />
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:ProdInst/ns1:Type" />
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:ProdInst/ns1:Descr" />
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:ProdInst/ns1:AdditionalAttributes/@gura" />
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns1:ProductGroups">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>,                    
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Basically I am trying to write the XSL to convert all these "Product" inner attribute values to the CSV format. I already struggled with overcome using the namespaces but still could not write up in the perfect format, sometimes the styles going on next line , and if I tried the generic one then the problem as could not read the additionalAtrributes values.
any help on this would be great.

Expecting output as 
 all the  tag inner attributes lined up in the CSV format with "," in order .

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:ns0="http://somenamspace/v1.0"
        xmlns:ns1="http://anothernamespace/v1.x"
        exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">


      <xsl:output  method="text" indent="no"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:Product"/>
      </xsl:template> 

      <xsl:template match="ns1:Product">
        <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:ProdInst"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:ProductGroups"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ns1:ProdInst">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:AllowedTypes"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:AdditionalAttributes"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ns1:AllowedTypes">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ns1:AdditionalAttributes">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
       </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried as above and got atleast all in the same line, but still its not comma seperated also the "AdditionalAttributes" are not included. can anybody help on this?

Comment: Show us an example of what you expect to receive.

Comment: I need just to print all the values of the nodes in the CSV formate regardless of whether its a node or attribute or even nested.                                       productName,12222,Conv,Conventional Loan,true,false,C,1111,2222 productName1,12223,Conv1,Conventional Loan1,true,false,C1,1111,2222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look this solution:

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="http://somenamspace/v1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://anothernamespace/v1.x"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">


  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ns1:Product">
      <xsl:call-template name="getProduct">
        <xsl:with-param name="Product" select="self::*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>

      </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getProduct">
    <xsl:param name="Product"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ProductContent">
      <xsl:for-each select="$Product/*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
              <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="*"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="@*">
              <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ProductContent,0,string-length($ProductContent))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getChild">
    <xsl:param name="Child"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Child/node()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* and not(@*)">
          <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
            <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="*"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="text()">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="*">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
            <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="*"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(*) and @*">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="$Child/@* and not($Child/node())">
      <xsl:for-each select="$Child/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
productName,12222,Conv,Conventional Loan,true,false,gura,C,1111,2222

      produ222222222ctName,12222,Conv,Conventional Loan,true,false,gura,C,1111,2222
```

Comment: : thank you Navin, this gives compilation error  JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error in 'self::*/* and not(self::*/@*)'. can you help on the script that results print the "trade" values every row. i almost got it worked but really not sure how should i get rid of the last comma after the "last value" of every "trade" values.