# XSLT to convert the nested elements with comma separated

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, transform

I am trying to just convert any xml file to CSV format. the issue as when the xml has nested / child elements those values are not output as comma separated. i have tried lot of examples in other posts but none of them works out as needed. I am a beginner to XSLT any help to this very helpful.

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
         <trade>
            <createdBy>1</createdBy>
            <createdOnDate>2</createdOnDate>
            <Payment>
               <indicator>3</indicator>
               <updateBy>4</updateBy>
            </Payment>
            <Parties>
               <partyId>5</partyId>
               <partyRoleTypeCode>6</partyRoleTypeCode>
            </Parties>
            <Product>
               <term>7</term>
               <shortDescription>8</shortDescription>
            </Product>
         </trade>
         <trade>
            <createdBy>10</createdBy>
            <createdOnDate>20</createdOnDate>
            <Payment>
               <indicator>30</indicator>
               <updateBy>40</updateBy>
            </Payment>
            <Parties>
               <partyId>50</partyId>
               <partyRoleTypeCode>60</partyRoleTypeCode>
            </Parties>
            <Product>
               <term>70</term>
               <shortDescription>80</shortDescription>
            </Product>
         </trade>

   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

thanks OkieOth. I have tried the modified script but it produce the output as

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,  ( i need to get rid of the last comma , looks keep this comma adding every row)
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80
```

Please help. i need to get rid of the ending comma after last value of the every line. note:the comma get removed only for the last row.

```
<xsl:template match="//S:Body">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//trade"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trade">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(following::*)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="getProduct">
      <xsl:with-param name="Product" select="//S:Body"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getProduct">
    <xsl:param name="Product"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Product/*">
      <xsl:variable name="ProductContent">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
              <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="self::*"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="@*">
              <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($ProductContent,0,string-length($ProductContent))"/>
      <xsl:text>

      </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getChild">
    <xsl:param name="Child"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Child/node()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="* and not(@*)">
          <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
            <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="*"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="text()">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="*">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
            <xsl:with-param name="Child" select="*"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(*) and @*">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="$Child/@* and not($Child/node())">
      <xsl:for-each select="$Child/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

  10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80
```

You may also check my previous post at [SOAP Response converting to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287687/soap-response-converting-to-csv/16515312#16515312)

Comment: thank you Navin, this gives compilation error JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker - Syntax error in 'self::*/* and not(self::*/@*)'. can you help on the script that results print the "trade" values every row. i almost got it worked but really not sure how should i get rid of the last comma after the "last value" of every "trade" values.

Comment: I have updated my response as per your request. Please have a look and revert back.