# Selecting and merging XML data when having the same node name

Tags: xml

I'm trying to select some data from the uniprot XML file, and I'm able to get most things I want out, but I'm having problems with getting data out that have more entries in the same node. To make it easier I'll use the well known CD collection data to show what I want. I would also like to know what's the easiest way of saving the output as a .csv or .txt file. Thanks! Let me know if anything is unclear.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <company>ABC</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <company>ABC</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Current XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title|artist|company"/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="title|artist|company">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
My CD Collection

Title           Artist          Company
Empire Burlesque    Bob Dylan   Columbia    ABC
Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler    CBS Records ABC
Greatest Hits   Dolly Parton    RCA
```

So I get all the data out that I want, but I would like the "company" results to be in 1 column, like this: Columbia;ABC

Also, in the file I'm using, it's common that there are more entries in the same node. However, for most I just want the first one and not all, only for some nodes. How can you distinguish these two? When I use

```
<xsl:for-each select="uniprot/entry"> 
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

it just returns the first item. So mostly I want this, but I think I need  for the other nodes where I want all entries. Would be great if you could help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified your xslt to get desired output:

**Updated xslt:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Company</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="title|artist|company"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="title|artist|company">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name()='company' and not(preceding-sibling::company)">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::company">
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::company">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='company' and preceding-sibling::company"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  <html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Company</th>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
            <td>Columbia;ABC</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
            <td>CBS Records;ABC</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Greatest Hits</td>
            <td>Dolly Parton</td>
            <td>RCA</td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

For CSV generation XSLT you may visit `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524580/xslt-to-convert-the-nested-elements-with-comma-seperated/16534999#16534999`

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. The only thing is that there's still an extra column with the second entry of company. How can you make sure this doesn't happen? (in the original file that would mean a lot of extra columns making processing so much harder)

Comment: Additional question (not necessary, but might make things more beautiful). Imagine 2 nodes with several entries, but number of entries is the same. First node contains for instance:
1  2  3  4  5
Second node contains:
One  Two  Three  Four  Five
Instead of getting the output:
1;2;3;4;5  One;Two;Three;Four;Five
Would it be possible to get this:
1-One;2-Two;3-Three;4-Four;5-Five

Comment: I have updated my response to solve your first query - extra column. Your second question is also aproachable but you need to share input XML and desired output.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!! 
I will update my question, give me some time :). Will use the original data for it, so it might be a bit less clear.

Comment: Data is posted. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think you should post new query to resolve new one as this one is already done.